# Will jump occur or not in these examples

Tags: assembly, x86

Hello I just started learning a bit about assembly because I am interested and I am curious how to answer these examples I found in my book. If you could also give me a brief understanding of why or why not this happens :)

What will happen when the code below is executed
   Choose One: Jump will occur    or   Jump will NOT occur

example 1

```
mov ax,0h 
cmp ax,0fh
jns loop1
```

example 2

```
mov ax,05h
mov bx,06h
cmp bx,ax 
js loop1
```

example 3

```
mov ax,0fh 
cmp ax,0h  
jns loop1
```

Comment: You're not really learning though if we give you the answers.... Has your book discussed how negative numbers are represented and the CPU flags? Do you know what a it means for the sign flag to be set after an operation?

Comment: Assemble, link them, see what a debugger shows you.

Comment: I understand that I am moving the value of 0h, to the ax register and then comparing 0h with 0fh. But I am confused about the jns vs js loop. with the cmp I am subtracting 0fh from ax but does the loop occur if I get a positive or a negative value?

Comment: From what I understand I believe the answers are Yes, No, No. When the result is negative then the jump does not happen and when it is positive then it does

Comment: JS is short for jump signed, or in other words jump if the result is negative. JNS is the reverse.

Comment: So in example 1 for instance jump if result is positive, but it is negative so there will be no jump right?

Comment: Exactly. `Cmp` is just a `sub` that does not change the regs.

Comment: No, `jns` jumps if the `cmp` result is non-negative, i.e. positive *or zero*.  Zero doesn't have its sign bit set, but is not positive.  Normally for signed comparisons you should use `jg` / `jge` / `jl` / `jle`.  Using `js` / `jns` semantically makes sense when you only care about the sign bit of the result, without caring about signed wrap-around.  See also https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/Jcc.  Also remember that most instructions set flags based on the result, including `add`, not just `cmp` or `sub`.